# Two MySQL Services on One Ubuntu Server Install

Tags: mysql, web-server, database, web-hosting

I am setting up a web staging environment and want to have a duplicate but separate MySQL service on the same machine. Development environments will connect to one service and staging environments will connect to another. This way when setting up a staging environment, I don't need to change database names, just the port on the MySQL server I connect to.

Is this easy and possible? I plan on manually copying the databases over to the staging environment when ready.

Comment: This was ultimately what I ended up following: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1154296.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. It's easy and possible if i understand your problem correctly.

Only use the tool that Mysql developed for this

[Instance Manager](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/instance-manager-startup-process.html)

Only one thing. U can't share the databases between the 2 instances in an easy way. Seems that the server "blocks" the files it's use and the database files too. But maybe there's a workaround for that. I dont know it.

Comment: Do you know why they removed it in MySQL 5.5? That seems that a weird thing to remove.

Comment: @Kirk Well, Have no idea. We use it in Windows, and the management tool is show as a "part" of the tray monitor. Get a lock at this URL.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/administrator/en/mysql-administrator-appendix-tray-monitor.html